# How I find the limit of $\frac{2^n}{e^{p(n)l}}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $m$ be a fixed natural number and suppose that $P_m$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients (in other words $P_m(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^ma_ix^i$ where  $a_i, 0\leq i\leq m$ are rational numbers).
>
> Prove that $$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n}{e^{P(n)}}=0\text{ or }\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{P(n)}}{2^n}=0.$$

I know that $\ln 2$ is an irrational number but I cannot use it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take logs and replace 2 by $c$.
Let $f(n) = n\ln(c)-p(n)$.

For large $n$, $p(n) \approx an^d$ 
where $d$ is the degree of $p$
and $a$ is the leading coefficient.

Then $f(n) \approx n\ln c -an^d$.

If $d \ge 2$ then
$f(n) \to -\infty$ if $a > 0$
and
$f(n) \to \infty$ if $a <0$.

Note that rationality does not matter -
only the degree and leading coefficient of $p(n)$.

(added after a comment)

If $d=1$ then
$p(n) = un+v$
so
$f(n) 
= n\ln(c)-un-v
= n(\ln(c)-u)-v
$.

Therefore the behavior of
$f(n)$ only depends on
the difference between
$\ln c$ and $u$.

Again,
rationality doesn't matter,
only the difference.

Comment: Thanks for this. Rationality maters when $d\leq 1$.

Comment: See my addition to my answer.

Comment: I think rationality assures that $u\neq \ln c$.

Comment: If it is equal then it depends on the constant term.